# Swift 4 JSON Parsing (Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead)

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swift4

I can't seem to get the structure right to decode this API. It's all dictionaries ({...}) yet my code keeps trying to deconstruct it as an array.

Error code:

```
 Error serialising json typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
2018-04-25 22:41:50.570999+0100 APItest[40741:729417] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-04-25 22:41:50.571127+0100 APItest[40741:729417] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
```

Link to API for parsing:
https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=BTC

Code:

```
func mainExchanges(){
    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=BTC"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else
    { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)
        { (data,response,err) in
            guard let data = data else
            {
                print("Error: No data to decode")
                return
            }
            do
            {
                let exchanges = try
                    JSONDecoder().decode([Exchanges].self, from: data)
                print(exchanges[0].data.rates.EUR)
            }
            catch let jsonErr
                {
                    print("Error serialising json",jsonErr)
                }
        }
    .resume()
}
```

Structure:

```
 struct Exchanges: Decodable   {
        let data: currency

        struct currency: Decodable {
            let currency: String
            let rates: Rates

            struct Rates: Decodable {
                let GBP: String
                let EUR: String
                let USD: String
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also tried structuring this as

```
struct Exchanges {} 
     struct currency {}
         struct rates {}
```

Comment: `[Exchanges].self` You are telling your `JSONDecoder` that it will have to decode an Array of `Exchanges` objects, while in fact it's an Array. Remove at least the square brackets.

Comment: didn't see this comment previously. Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Data is not Array, it is Dictionary. 
To Parse it, you can use:

```
let exchanges = try
                JSONDecoder().decode(Exchanges.self, from: data)
```

If you want to convert it in array then make new Object of array as:

```
let exchange: [Exchanges] = [exchanges]
```

Comment: knew it was something stupid! i did try it without brackets originally but i think I the struct layouts were wrong when i did . Many thanks Chanchal. P.s. i did upvote, but as i have less than 15 rep it says it won't display